# Functions that are both Abel and Bernstein?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, functional-equations

How many functions are known to be both Abel functions and Bernstein functions ?

An abel function is the $\alpha$ function that solves an Abel equation , see

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation

And a Bernstein function is this :

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions

So a Bernstein function is the same as a complete monotone function. Or total monotone function. It is just terminology.

This question has also been posted on the tetration forum by my friend.

http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1163

Comment: Log(log(x)) perhaps ? Natural log intended.

Comment: There must be infinitely many ... if we can express them is another matter.